# Does Google App Engine has a support for Joomla?

Tags: google-app-engine, joomla

Does Google App Engine has a support for Joomla?

Answer (score 4):

Joomla runs in PHP - App Engine runs Python & Java code, so without large amounts of modification no I do not believe App Engine will let you host Joomla out of the box - however according to this post, you may be able to run PHP Scripts using a Java implementation of PHP: http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/run-php-on-the-google-app-engine/

Comment: This is not longer very relevant.. since App Engine now supports officially PHP.. still not sure about Joomla though ;)

Answer (score 4):

AppEngine now supports PHP: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/

In this video they demo WordPress so I guess Joomla will work too.

https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/333055646

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Here is the link to install Joomla on GAE

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=828565&p=3114492